# TypeError when using *ngFor to initialise a component by passing an object

Tags: angular

I have an component `device-row` which I want to use to represent a number of different devices, all organised into rows via bootstrap. In order to construct these device rows I need to be able to pass the component a different `device` object for each device. Using the details of each device a new `device-row` is constructed and rendered to the DOM.

Here is my DeviceRowComponent.

```
export class DeviceRowComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() serial: Serial;

  serialNumber: string;
  connected: number;
  disconnected: number;
  neverConnected: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serialNumber = this.serial.serialNumber;
    this.connected = this.serial.connected;
    this.disconnected = this.serial.disconnected;
    this.neverConnected = this.serial.neverConnected;
  }

}
```

Here is my HomeComponent, which makes use of a service to return some Serial objects. The serial objects are passed to a `device-row` in order to initialise the row via the HTML template.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  serials: Serial[];

  constructor(private serialService: SerialService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serials = this.serialService.getSerials();
  }

}
```

And here is the template for my HomeComponent (Updated)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let serial of serials">
      <app-device-row [serial]="serial"></app-device-row>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently I'm getting the following error.

```
HomeComponent.html:12 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'serialNumber' of undefined
    at DeviceRowComponent.ngOnInit
```

This is occuring because the `device-row.component.ts` file is executing its logic to set values before the `serial` object has had its value set, throwing a type error. The order in which Angular seems to execute javascript seems to go against what I had in my head. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: @Vega My `[serial]` is in reference to my `@Input() serial : Serial` in my device-row, while the `"serial"` is in reference to the declared serial within `let serial of serials`, is this not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code from `ngOnInit` to `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook.

`ngOnChanges` will gets called whenever a property binding value gets changed.

In your case, `serial` value will be passed only after getting the data from a service call. so it's an async operation. `ngOnInit` gets invoked before `serial` value assigned to the property.

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.serial) {
      this.serialNumber = this.serial.serialNumber;
      this.connected = this.serial.connected;
      this.disconnected = this.serial.disconnected;
      this.neverConnected = this.serial.neverConnected;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, I've done what you said and the code now works. However only one of the device-rows is rendered, despite there being 3 serial objects within the Serials array. I have updated the OP with the new html for my HomeComponent. Why aren't the other two rendering?

Comment: can you share what you get in `serials[]`.

Comment: It was an unrelated problem, I've managed to fix it now. I've marked your answer as correct, thanks!

Comment: Hope, the answer solved the problem. and you learned what's the difference between ngOnInit and ngOnChanges as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@Input() set serial(value) {
if(value){
  this.serialNumber = value.serialNumber || null;
};
```

Instead of `@Input() serial;`

and don't pass `serial object data into OnInit`. It should be in your `@Input` function. This will update your table row run time if any row changed.

And also make sure `serialNumber` and all other object available in your class or interface.